# How to get android studio to offer nougat with google apis for emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

I have android studio 2.1.3. In the SDK manager, I have downloaded Nougat:

[image]

I want to create an emulator now that uses the google apis, but I don't have that as an option:

[image]

How do I get access to that? Otherwise I can't test my apps.

Thanks

Comment: Nothing you can do, its too new.

Comment: But they are rolling it out to live devices already - they won't give developers a way to test?

Comment: The only way to test for now is to use the real device with Nougat.